# Is it possible to create an IF statement that changes formatting?

Tags: excel

Example:
Say column A has a date in it. If column B has a 5, and if today's date is 5 days after the date in A column, then the cell of column A turns red.
However, if column B has a 6, it only turns red after 15 days.

If played around for ages and can't figure out how to make this work.

EDIT:  I know it's conditional formatting that I need, I just can't figure out how to get it to work correctly.

Comment: Look into conditional formatting, it'll do what you want.

Comment: This is job for [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1). There are about gazillion tutorials online.

Comment: This would be handled through Conditional Formatting.  The Conditional Formatting formula you're looking for is probably something like `=OR(AND($B1=5,$A1+5<TODAY()),AND($B1=6,$A1+15<TODAY()))`

Comment: Yes I know it's conditional formatting, I have read a "gazillion" tutorials on it already, unfortunately none of them answer my question.

Comment: Then please edit your question to include your attempts. I don't see why Conditional Formatting *won't* work, so it's just an issue of getting the formula right.  This isn't a "code for me" site, we expect folks to show their efforts.  Three people have suggested Conditional Formatting, you say it doesn't work, but don't provide a single thread of help to us.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a third column with logic such as if(now()>a1+b1, TRUE,FALSE). If you set your conditional formatting to work off this column it should format A as you wish.